# Deleting items in TListBox using a separate button on RAD Studio

Tags: c++

I am creating a simple calculator app to learn how to use RAD, but could not figure out how to delete items in the ListBox by clicking "CLR". The "CLR" button should be able to clear out both the input box and the answer box. I am using C++ not Delphi. If you need anything more in the codes please let me know.

[image: example of calc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TListBox` has a public  [`Clear()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Clear) method, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ClrButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    InputListBox->Clear();
    AnswerListBox->Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that function existed.

Comment: @SalSo You would have, if you had simply looked at what methods were available in the `TListBox` class, either through Code Completion, or documentation, or just looking at the `Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp` header file.